# Depends on other local module

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, repository

I have two modules and one links the other one. When I install the second one the build failed saying me 'Could not find artifact'. Here's poms:

```
    <groupId>xyz.upperlevel.graphicengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>graphicengine</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>FINAL</version>

    <modules>
        <module>graphicengine-api</module>
        <module>gamelauncher</module>
        <module>testgame</module>
    </modules>
```

This is the pom of the main project.

Then here's the pom of one of its modules (are all the equal):

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>xyz.upperlevel.graphicengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>graphicengine</artifactId>
    <version>FINAL</version>
</parent>

<groupId>xyz.upperlevel.graphicengine.testgame</groupId>
<artifactId>testgame</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

I have the module A that links to the module B all inside the MAIN project. When I build the module A all goes fine (since it has no dependency from local modules) but when I build the module B it failed. This is the error:

```
Failed to execute goal on project gamelauncher: Could not resolve dependencies for project xyz.upperlevel.graphicengine.gamelauncher:gamelauncher:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at xyz.upperlevel.graphicengine.api:graphicengine-api:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for xyz.upperlevel.graphicengine.api:graphicengine-api:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find xyz.upperlevel.graphicengine:graphicengine:pom:FINAL in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

How to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the right coordinates of your artifacts? Maven should have created the repository automatically. See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html for more informations on repositories. For a detailed spec for artifacts and dependencies see https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html.

To be able to help you in a better way, please provide some code.

Comment: I think that this error is given since I don't specify that I want to use local repository dependencies how can I do it?

Comment: Please provide the poms and your use cmandline, then we can determine the cause.

Comment: Maven generates and uses the local repository automatically, no need to specify any options or configuration for this. Usually this repo is found in USERHOME/.m2. Obviously USERHOME depends on your OS.

Comment: Yeah I know the folder .m2. I edited the question, now should be more clear.

Comment: Well, you are able to build a sub-module directly in the corresponding path as well, as long as the other Module is build already and lying in the local repo.

Comment: One more thing while we are in it. Usually the Version in the parent (Main Module) is the same then the one of its Childs in a Multi Module project. This makes your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

**I HAVE SOLVED: I WAS BUILDING FROM MODULES PATH AND INSTEAD OF BUILDING FROM ROOT PROJECT PATH! DON'T FALL IN MY SAME ERROR!**